# web-based report

Tags: java

Example demonstrates how a web-based report can be created by using a database datasource

Thanks
venu

Comment: Example demonstrates how a web-based report can be created by using a database datasource

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: [Question title that doesn't describe the problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are two different java products that can produce web reports:

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports)
[BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/)

Both are good products, but do check the licensing of the product that you chose.

There are plenty of examples on the web that show you how to use each of these productions.